# Anonymous SharePoint Users and people search core results web part

Tags: sharepoint, search, moss, anonymous

Can anyone tell me how to allow anonymous SharePoint MOSS users to view people search core results web parts? When they try to access pages containing this web part, they are prompted to login.

All the best

Answer (score 1):

Your can have a quick look here: [People search to anonymous users in MOSS](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/b253a26c-7ba4-4b85-aafb-445de6d90c2d/)

There are some people discussing the same issue and have found a couple of solutions.